# Ui Dialog not responding while using time.sleep()

Tags: python

I like to run loop but iterations I have to pause for some seconds
I found solution to use `time.sleep(5)` while using this function in Windows my Dialog is getting freeze and "not responding". My label is not updating as well
Any solutions? Check `main.py` pause in loop catch this issue. As my window or dialog is getting freeze and not responding status

**UiUi.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        if not Dialog.objectName():
            Dialog.setObjectName(u"Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(940, 640)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Dialog.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Dialog.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily(u"Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        Dialog.setFont(font)
        Dialog.setFocusPolicy(Qt.WheelFocus)
        Dialog.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: none;\n"
"image: none;\n"
"background-color: #000;\n"
"color: #00ff00;\n"
"width: 1500px;\n"
"height: 1500px;")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(40, 340, 822, 142))
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton{\n"
"   border: 2px solid #00ff00;\n"
"   border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"   border: 2px solid #e61a21;\n"
"   color: #e61a21;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"   border: 2px solid #042f57;\n"
"   color: #042f57;\n"
"}")
        self.label = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(80, 110, 821, 204))
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"Ffff TffffSfffff NOW", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"Fufff 0/0", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
#from PySide2.QtCore import *
#rom PySide2.QtGui import *
#from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from UiUi import Ui_Dialog

#create app

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#init 
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

#hook logic

counter = 0
domain = "lols.com"

requests = {
                "Step1" : {
                    "q" : "l1",
                    "msg" : f"{domain} - Brasil best lol"
                },
                "Step2" : {
                    "q" : "l1",
                    "msg" : f"{domain} - Argentina best lol"
                },
                "Step3" : {
                    "q" : "l1",
                    "msg" : f"{domain} - Espanhol best lol"
                },
                "Step4" : {
                    "q" : "l1",
                    "msg" : f"{domain} - Colombia best lol"
                },
                "Step5" : {
                    "q" : "l1",
                    "msg" : f"{domain} - Asia best lol"
                },
            }
dictionary_len = len(requests)

def run_kki():
    import time

    global counter
    global domain
    global requests
    global dictionary_len

    """
    while counter < dictionary_len:
        time.sleep(5)
        counter += 1
        dictionary_key = "Step" + str(counter)
        q = requests[dictionary_key]["q"]
        msg = requests[dictionary_key]["msg"]
        print(msg)
        print(f'Ffffff: {counter}/{dictionary_len}')
        ui.label.setText(f'Ffffff: {counter}/{dictionary_len}');
    """
    
    for index, request in requests.items():
        print(request['msg'])
        #Here I do a 5 sec pause for iteractions and got freeze my DialogUi
        time.sleep(5) 

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(run_kki)

#Main Loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `qWait`

```py
from PyQt4 import QtTest
QtTest.QTest.qWait(msecs)
```